# DataGrid in DataTemplate not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to make a `wpf` application in which there would be a `datagrid` with the ability to click on a line and get another `datagrid`.

For this, I created a `Model`:

```
public class TestData
{
    public DataTable First { get; set; }
    public DataTable Second { get; set; }
}
```

Created `ViewModel` as follows:

```
public class ViewModelTestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TestData _testCollection;
    public TestData TestCollection
    {
        get => _testCollection;
        set
        {
            _testCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TestCollection");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private DataTable _first;
    private DataTable _second;

    public ViewModelTestClass(DataTable first, DataTable second)
    {
        TestCollection = new TestData();
        _first = first;
        _second = second;
        BindData();
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        TestCollection.First = _first;
        TestCollection.Second = _second;
    }
}
```

And some part of the `View`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RowDetailTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="RowDetailGrid"
              Width="470"
              Height="Auto"
              Margin="5">
            <DataGrid 
                DataContext="{Binding Path = TestCollection.Second, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                >
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


        <DataGrid  
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="6" 
            Grid.RowSpan="2" 
            Name="StatisticDataGrid" 
            Margin="5" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection.First}" 
            CanUserAddRows="False" 
            ColumnWidth="*" 
            CanUserSortColumns="False" 
            MouseDoubleClick="StatisticDataGrid_OnMouseDoubleClick" 
            RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource RowDetailTemplate}"
            RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="dataGrid1_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged"
            >
            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="RowHeaderToggleButton"
                                  Click="ToggleButton_Click"
                                  Cursor="Hand" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

`View` code behind:

```
private void SetContext()
{
    var firstTable = GetTableFirst();
    var secondTable = GetTableSecond();
    this.DataContext = new ViewModelTestClass(firstTable, secondTable);
}
```

The first DataGrid fills up fine, but when I click on a row, the second `DataGrid` shows nothing, although the secondTable is full and not `Null`

What am I doing wrong and how to deal with it?

Comment: Do the rows have a property called `TestCollection.Second`? No, they're DataTables. `TestCollection.Second` is a member of your viewmodel. Row detail is the detail of the row: The DataContext in the RowDetailsTemplate is the parent row in the main datagrid. Also, you are trying to set `DataContext` to the collection instead of `ItemsSource`.

Comment: ...so you need to figure out what you want for row details, and how to get it where you want it. Were you updating TestCollection.Second in the SelectionChanged event for the outer grid? `ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.TestCollection.Second, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"` should work for that, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datagrid in the rowDetailTemplate  should be

```
<DataGrid 
            DataContext="{Binding Path = DataContext.TestCollection.Second,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid,Mode=FindAncestor}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}"    >
</DataGrid>
```

because the rowDetailTemplate's datacontext is in datarow,it cannot find the 'Second' property in datarow.

you need to set datacontext to TestCollection.

Other tips:

First

you can use the below code.

```
private TestData _testCollection;
    public TestData TestCollection
    {
        get => _testCollection;
        set
        {
            _testCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

[CallMemberName] will auto set parameter, so you don't need to send the parameter.

Secondly, if you want to dynamically change the datatable in code behind.

Testdata should implement INotifyPropertyChanged

you need to raise property changed on your First and Second property.

```
 public class TestData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public DataTable First
    {
        get { return _First; }
        set
        {
            _First = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private DataTable _First;
    public DataTable Second
    {
        get { return _Second; }
        set
        {
            _Second = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private DataTable _Second;

}
```

Finally, when binding is not working, you can check the visual studio output from debug.

it will tell you why the binding fail

Comment: It works, thanks! I have another question. How can I add another datagrid to the second grid, which is in the datatemplate?

Comment: You can create other rowdatatemplate and set the rowDatatemplate of datagrid which is in original rowDatatemplate.